# PHP use str_slug without changing Upper Cases

Tags: php, string, laravel

Want to change text into slug using `str_slug`. It works **perfectly** for different cases, but I want it to work **without changing UpperCases**, i.e.

ex: *Hello    --- World*  => *Hello-World*

Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: Please show us your current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on a question on [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/retaining-case-when-using-str-slug) you can create your own version of the helper function, that leaves out [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php):

```
public static function slug($title, $separator = '-', $language = 'en')
{
    $title = static::ascii($title, $language);
    // Convert all dashes/underscores into separator
    $flip = $separator == '-' ? '_' : '-';
    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($flip).']+!u', $separator, $title);
    // Replace @ with the word 'at'
    $title = str_replace('@', $separator.'at'.$separator, $title);
    // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace.

    // With lower case: $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', mb_strtolower($title));
    $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', $title);

    // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);
    return trim($title, $separator);
}
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f7d029bb777efc0191d6f514d433b4d9b8497d2)

[Original implementation](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Str.php#L414)

Answer (score 2):

Heres the implementation that `str_slug` uses:

```
/**
 * Generate a URL friendly "slug" from a given string.
 *
 * @param  string  $title
 * @param  string  $separator
 * @param  string  $language
 * @return string
 */
public static function slug($title, $separator = '-', $language = 'en')
{
    $title = static::ascii($title, $language);

    // Convert all dashes/underscores into separator
    $flip = $separator == '-' ? '_' : '-';

    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($flip).']+!u', $separator, $title);

    // Replace @ with the word 'at'
    $title = str_replace('@', $separator.'at'.$separator, $title);

    // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', mb_strtolower($title));

    // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

    return trim($title, $separator);
}
```

Simply extend from this methods class or copy it to a new class of your own and then remove any code that converts case.

Comment: Are you suggesting to change code in `vendor` folder?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting either extend or if you must, copy it to a new class. Don't modify files in vendor for the sake of the children.

Comment: Yes, changing files in Vendor will be overwritten when you run "composer update" or "composer install"